# How to avoid "hub_port_status failed"error messages?

Tags: usb, system-installation

On startup and on closing Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) displays many lines like

`[   14.212517] hub 1-8:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)`

Then the computer seems to work ok, although there seems to be some HD activity all the time. The file(s) dmesg.log are flooded with the above lines. I suspect there is some kind of an USB conflict. It is on a 10 years old desktop with dual boot to Windows XP. 
What should I do, where should I look?

Comment: I googled around for a minute and I found a couple of cases where shutting down the computer and disconnecting the power for a while helped avoiding USB-related errors and delays.

Comment: Your hardware is failing!  Start saving money for a new computer and read the following Q&A: [What's a good back-up strategy for 1 PC](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)

Comment: @Fabby That's all great, but could you give us a reason as to what is happening and a source as to why one should believe your statement?

Comment: @PeterRaeves I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is **either a hardware or a firmware issue.**  Both are off-topic on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @Fabby Then why didn't I have this problem before the update?

Comment: @PeterRaeves: post a [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask), link to this one and give more information like your hardware.  With the information we've got here, there's not much we can do.

Comment: @Fabby [Here](http://askubuntu.com/q/616555/258487) you go. I'm not completely sure what specific hardware I should specify though.

Comment: @Fabby i am the OP of that question... Also I don't see what the point is referring to this question as it will be closed soon anyway?

Comment: Sorry!  Dumb comment deleted...